# How to match the second invocation on mock?

Tags: mockito, matcher

As shown below, I want to check the mock.fireEvent() get invoked with specific event(event2 here)

```
mock.fireEvent(event1);

mock.fireEvent(event2);

verify(mock).fireEvent(matcherToCheckTheFieldOfEvent2);
```

But get an error indicating that

```
  verify(mock).fireEvent(matcherToCheckTheFieldOfEvent2);
```

will try to match first invoking

```
  mock.fireEvent(argThat(event1));
```

The question is how to let event2 get matched?

Matcher looks like this:

```
    private class IsEvent2 extends ArgumentMatcher<Event2>
    {
      @Override
      public boolean matches(Object arg)
      {
                return ((Event2) arg).methodGotCalled();
      }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please add the exact error message you get? Adding more of you junit test code would also help.

Comment: Full test code is quite a lot and the main idead is the type of  captured event is Event1 and can't be cast to Event2 and I add the Matcher code

Answer (score 0):

This is and old thread but I got into this problem recently and solved it by using `ArgumentCaptor` to capture the List of fired events and asserting the expected events are present on the list.

```
ArgumentCaptor<SomeEvent> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(SomeEvent.class);
verify(mock, times(2)).fire(argument.capture());
```

`argument` will then have a list of captured events and you can assert them individually

```
assertThat(argument.getAllValues(), hasItems(
    new SomeEventMatcher(event1),
    new SomeEventMatcher(event2)
));
```

And the matcher looks like this:

```
static class SomeEventMatcher extends ArgumentMatcher<SomeEvent> {
    private SomeEvent expected;

    public SomeEventMatcher(SomeEvent expected) {
        this.expected = expected;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(Object argument) {
        if (argument == null) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            SomeEvent event = (SomeEvent) argument;
            // the fields that you want to compare with the matcher
            return new EqualsBuilder()
                    .append(expected.getField1(), event.getField1())
                    .append(expected.getField2(), event.getField2())
                    .build();
        }
    }
}
```